Blood money as punishment for marital rape
Do the narrations below suggest blood money is due for marital rape as a ruling?
They are derived from musanaf ibn abi shaybah
186- الرَّجُلُ يَسْتَكْرِهُ الْمَرْأَةَ فَيُفْضِيهَا.
28475- حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ ، عَن دَاوُد ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ شُعَيْبٍ ؛ أَنَّ رَجُلاً اسْتَكْرَهَ امْرَأَةً فَأَفْضَاهَا ، فَضَرَبَهُ عُمَرُ الْحَدَّ ، وَغَرَّمَهُ ثُلُثَ دِيَتِهَا.
28476- حَدَّثَنَا زَيْدُ بْنُ الْحُبَابِ ، عَن خَالِدِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللهِ ، عَن خَالِدٍ الْحَذَّاءِ ، عَنْ أَبَانَ بْنِ عُثْمَانَ ؛ أَنَّهُ رُفِعَ إِلَيْهِ رَجُلٌ تَزَوَّجَ جَارِيَةً فَأَفْضَاهَا ، فَقَالَ فِيهَا هُوَ وَعُمَرُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الْعَزِيزِ : إِنْ كَانَتْ مِمَّنْ يُجَامَعُ مِثْلُهَا فَلاَ شَيْءَ عَلَيْهِ ، وَإِنْ كَانَتْ مِمَّنْ لاَ يُجَامَعُ مِثْلُهَا ، فَعَلَيْهِ ثُلُثُ الدِّيَةِ.
28477- حَدَّثَنَا وَكِيعٌ ، عَن شَيْخٍ ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ ، عَن زَيْدِ بْنِ ثَابِتٍ ؛ فِي الرَّجُلِ يُفضِي الْمَرْأَةَ ، قَالَ : إِذَا أَمْسَكَ أَحَدُهُمَا عَنِ الآخَرِ فَالثُّلُثُ ، وَإِنْ لَمْ يُمْسِكْ فَالدِّيَةُ.

Blood money is due if an injury is caused involving a permanent loss for the victim.
All of these narrations state that if a woman is injured due to sexual intercourse, i.e. develops a Fistula - her private parts tear and become one - then the man is liable to compensate the woman for the damage he caused. The reports are not about marital rape.
Following is my translation of the three reports you have quoted:

حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ ، عَن دَاوُد ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ شُعَيْبٍ ؛ أَنَّ رَجُلاً اسْتَكْرَهَ امْرَأَةً فَأَفْضَاهَا ، فَضَرَبَهُ عُمَرُ الْحَدَّ ، وَغَرَّمَهُ ثُلُثَ دِيَتِهَا
A man forced a woman (a stranger) and caused her to develop a fistula. Umar whipped the man as a Hadd punishment (for fornication) and made him responsible for compensating the woman by paying a third of the blood money


حَدَّثَنَا زَيْدُ بْنُ الْحُبَابِ ، عَن خَالِدِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللهِ ، عَن خَالِدٍ الْحَذَّاءِ ، عَنْ أَبَانَ بْنِ عُثْمَانَ ؛ أَنَّهُ رُفِعَ إِلَيْهِ رَجُلٌ تَزَوَّجَ جَارِيَةً فَأَفْضَاهَا ، فَقَالَ فِيهَا هُوَ وَعُمَرُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الْعَزِيزِ : إِنْ كَانَتْ مِمَّنْ يُجَامَعُ مِثْلُهَا فَلاَ شَيْءَ عَلَيْهِ ، وَإِنْ كَانَتْ مِمَّنْ لاَ يُجَامَعُ مِثْلُهَا ، فَعَلَيْهِ ثُلُثُ الدِّيَةِ.
A man married a young girl and caused her to caused her to develop a fistula.
Aban ibn Uthman and Umar ibn Abddul Aziz said that if the girl is (physically mature enough) such that intercourse is had with one like her then there is nothing due on the husband. However if she is like one with whom intercourse is not had (due to physical immaturity) then the husband is liable for a third of the blood money.


حَدَّثَنَا وَكِيعٌ ، عَن شَيْخٍ ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ ، عَن زَيْدِ بْنِ ثَابِتٍ ؛ فِي الرَّجُلِ يُفضِي الْمَرْأَةَ ، قَالَ : إِذَا أَمْسَكَ أَحَدُهُمَا عَنِ الآخَرِ فَالثُّلُثُ ، وَإِنْ لَمْ يُمْسِكْ فَالدِّيَةُ.
Zaid in Thabit was asked about a man who caused a woman to develop a fistula. He said that if one pathway is still able to shut the other then a third of the blood money is due, and if it does not (meaning she can not hold back urine, feces or bear a child) then full blood money is due.

